# I can't get the "Curious" badge, even if my total questions' score is actually positive!

Tags: support, questions, badges

[image: Curious badge not earned]

My profile page keeps saying that I have a negative question record. But that doesn't really seem true, because I actually have an 85+ scored question, and about 8 5+ Questions.
I *did* delete many questions in my lifetime, but those can't actually have so many downvotes in order to affect the positive record.
**Am I missing something here?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question), you can see the formula given for what defines your "question record." Note that it doesn't say "positive question **score**", but "positive question **record**".

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted) / total questions >= 0.5

Thus, the actual score of your questions *do not matter*. Your +86 question only counts as 1 positive question, not 86 positive score, because only whether a question is positive or negative matters. Furthermore, deleted or closed questions will count against this record.

I can't see your deleted questions, but based on what I *can* see, it looks like there are 6 downvoted questions and 14 closed questions (these effects stack, so since some of your downvoted questions were also marked as dupes, they count against you *twice*).

So, based on these numbers, (75 - 20)/75 = **0.73**. Assuming there have been no deleted questions, you *should* have the Curious badge as well as the Inquisitive badge.

However, you mention that you have deleted multiple questions in the past. Say you have deleted 10 downvoted and closed questions, for example. This would count as a big -30 against your question record, while only adding 10 total questions. Thus, the formula would now look like

(85 - 50)/85 = **0.41**,

which would *not* qualify as a positive question record.

Comment: Nothing says "do the right thing and delete poor questions" like being triple punished for it for an interwebz trophy.

Comment: @Ellesedil well actually, deleting it counts against you too, so it'd be better to leave them undeleted

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was being sarcastic while pointing out how it seems silly to not treat questions uniquely when totaling up scores for badges.

Comment: @Ellesedil oh, oh, I got you. But yeah, it prevents people from gaming the system by just hiding their bad posts and pretending they didn't happen. In fact, it punishes people who try to do that by counting them extra times.

Comment: Eh, seems short sited. This could be encouragement to leave bad questions around instead of doing the "right" thing and deleting them. I'm fine with the system still checking deleted questions for negative/closed/deleted statuses. But I don't really see how counting individual questions multiple times for gamification awards is beneficial in any way for the site. It'd encourage some people to do the "wrong" thing instead.

Comment: @Ellesedil, if a question really should be deleted, then 10k+ users or mods can have it deleted. If a user repeatedly posts questions that garner a single downvote then deletes them to save their rep, *that* is an abuse of the system. I realize these are answers, but a good recent example would be [posts](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295310/162442) like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295306/162442), [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295302/162442), or [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/295286/162442). (Note: 10k required for all links)

Comment: @Ellesedil questions should be improved wherever possible instead of deletion. Deletion is an absolute last resort, closure for any reason other than duplicate is supposed to be a midway point where the question is either improved and reopened or eventually deleted.